# Rendering Template in Meteor and Iron Router depending on value in document

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to render a template depending on a value of a field in a document.

I tried using a switch case in a helper but the return value comes out incorrect.

### units_list.html

```
<template name="unitsList">
{{#each units}}
  {{> unitItem}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

### units_list.js

```
Template.unitsList.helpers({
  units: function() {
    return Units.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});
  }
});
```

### unit_item.html

```
<template name="unitItem">
  <a href="{{unitType}}">{{name}}</a>
</template>
```

### unit_item.js

```
Template.unitItem.helpers({
  unitType: function() {
    var unitType = this.unitType;
    switch(unitType){
      case 'first': return "{{pathFor 'unitPageFirst'}}";
      case 'second': return "{{pathFor 'unitPageSecond'}}";
    }
  }
});
```

I'm either going about this the wrong way or missing something elementary...

I've cut out a lot of code to focus on the problem.

Any ideas on how to get this working, or any suggestions on how to do it better?

Comment: try replace `return "{{pathFor 'unitPageFirst'}}";` with `return Router.path('unitPageFirst');`, and add `break` statement to switch-case

Comment: Could you post your publication?

Comment: Meteor.publish('units', function() {
 return Units.find();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return uncompiled Spacebars strings from JS at execution time.

You can either use `Router.path` to get the path for your routes within your template helper :

```
Template.unitItem.helpers({
  unitType: function() {
    var unitType = this.unitType;
    switch(unitType){
      case 'first':
        return Router.path('unitPageFirst', this);
      case 'second':
        return Router.path('unitPageSecond', this);
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can use plain Spacebars by declaring template helpers to check against the `unitType`.

HTML

```
<template name="unitItem">
  {{#if unitTypeIs 'unitTypeFirst'}}
    <a href="{{pathor 'unitTypeFirst'}}">{{name}}</a>
  {{/if}}
  {{#if unitTypeIs 'unitTypeSecond'}}
    <a href="{{pathor 'unitTypeSecond'}}">{{name}}</a>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.unitItem.helpers({
  unitTypeIs: function(unitType){
    return this.unitType == unitType;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem I am getting with this is that now it's looking for route called 'unitPageFirst'. If I leave the switch case out, I can get to the specific unit's page and the path is then /units/dsifuh786s8df76 (id number). And If i create the route, would I then need to pass the unit's _id?

Comment: I have created the route and now it routes correctly to /unitPageFirst/_id. However my end goal is to have the user fill in the type field and the app creates the route using that value with a dynamically created layout template based on other fields the user filled in on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Rendering Templates in the Iron-router guide, specifically the **this.render('xyz');** statement

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates